# Google Analytics Cookies for average time

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, session-cookies

I'm going to use Google analytic for windows based application and i need to send average time details to Google analytic.
 according to my research i found __utmb and __utmc cookies are used to measure time.

as mentioned in [Google Analyics Cookie](http://www.morevisibility.com/analyticsblog/from-__utma-to-__utmz-google-analytics-cookies.html)

> **The __utmb and __utmc Cookies**
>
> The B and C cookies are brothers, working together to calculate how
>   long a visit takes. __utmb takes a timestamp of the exact moment in
>   time when a visitor enters a site, while __utmc takes a timestamp of
>   the exact moment in time when a visitor leaves a site. __utmb expires
>   at the end of the session. __utmc waits 30 minutes, and then it
>   expires. You see, __utmc has no way of knowing when a user closes
>   their browser or leaves a website, so it waits 30 minutes for another
>   pageview to happen, and if it doesn’t, it expires.

so from my desktop application i tried to passed url which is suited for these cookie value. i found detail description of ‘__utmb’ cookie value, as below. [Cookie Explained](http://www.tutkiun.com/2011/04/a-google-analytics-cookie-explained.html)

> ‘_*utmb’ is used to establish and continue a user session with your
>   site and ‘*_utmc’ operates in conjunction with the ‘_*utmb’ cookie to
>   determine whether or not to establish a new session for the user.
>   The example of ‘*_utmb’ 
>   cookie is
>   126210440.14.0.1302875964860
>
> ```
> 126210440 : Domain hash, unique for each domain
> 14 : Number of page views in current session
> 0 : Starts with 10 and this count decreases to 0 after every outbound link click
> 1302875964860 : Timestamps of current session time
> ```

but couldn't find details about  **__utmc** cookie value details.

**My Problems:**

1. What are the parameters of __utmc?

   **OR**
2. Is there any other way to send average time to Google analytic?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

__utmc is deprecated. you have to use __utmz campaign value.